FATAL: OneSignal AppId: (null) - AppId is null or format is invalid, stopping initialization
I'm kinda new to react native and I'm trying to build my app which uses One Signal for push notifications,
the problem is that whenever I import OneSignal like so:
import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal'

I get the following message in the console:
FATAL: OneSignal AppId: (null) - AppId is null or format is invalid, stopping initialization.
Example usage: 'b2f7f966-d8cc-11ed-ced1-df8705be55ca'

The app keeps on running but whenever I try to use the OneSignal object I imported it raises an error since OneSignal is not initialised thus being undefined:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Debug' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Does anyone know what is happening here?
I've tried looking for an answer online but all I found was about the operations done with the imported object and not with the import itself
